# My breaker panel is in a sump closet, should I move it?

Tags: circuit-breaker, sump-pump

I just purchased a new home and I'm going to replace the breaker panel (it's full and I want expansion room).  The panel is located directly above the sump pump in a small closet in the corner of the basement.  I was wondering if I should have it moved when it's replaced?  The one electrician I talked to (my realtor is a former electrician and also my Uncle) said it's not hurting anything.

Comment: I think they're probably right. I might move it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off -- if the sump/sump pump protrude above the surrounding floor level, then they are a 110.26(E)(1)(a) violation:

> (a) *Dedicated Electrical Space.* The space equal to the width and depth of
>   the equipment and extending from the floor to a height of 1.8 m (6 ft) above 
>   the equipment or to the structural ceiling, whichever is lower, shall be 
>   dedicated to the electrical installation. No piping, ducts, leak protection 
>   apparatus, or other equipment foreign to the electrical installation shall be 
>   located in this zone.

Second -- even if the sump doesn't violate the letter of 110.26(E)(1)(a), it could still be seen as a violation of 110.26, as it poses a potential tripping or wet-surface hazard to someone working on the equipment:

> **110.26 Spaces About Electrical Equipment.** Access and working space shall 
>   be provided and maintained about all electrical equipment to permit ready and 
>   safe operation and maintenance of such equipment.

So, I'd move the panel if feasible; at the very least, I'd talk to the AHJ about it -- I'd want to have an official interpretation on file for such a situation, even if the panel can't move.

Also, will the closet itself let the panel door open the full 90deg, and is there a space in front of the panel *above* the floor at least 30" wide and 36" deep? If either of those things are false, then the panel must move anyway, as the NEC working clearance rules in 110.26(A) would then be violated.

Comment: Only the discharge pipe extends above the floor, and the panel is so small that there is plenty of clearance.  I'm replacing it anyway so I will mention moving it and see what the electrician recommends.  Thanks for finding the related NEC entries.

Comment: @Joel Unfortunately, that discharge pipe is enough to count as a 110.26(E)(1)(a) violation.  Your AHJ may be willing to give you a variance of some sort if moving the panel is impractical, though.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever put in the pump and/or the closet most likely created a "working clearance" code violation.

I'd move it if you could. Doesn't sound like it would have to go far.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it violates the working clearance in the electrical code.  I have seen tons of sump pumps under boxes.  Tons.  I have never seen them mentioned in inspection reports or in disclosures nor the city say anything after doing a new home inspection.  Most sump pumps have covers and are flat on the floor and really there should be less water by the sump pump than other parts of your basement.

However this is all about the interpretation of the local inspector.  Really you should just call your city hall and ask to talk to the inspector - send them a picture or have them come over.  Ask if you upgraded would you be required to move the box.  They are the only ones that can tell you this.

Is it best to have a sump pump under your box... No.   But would a normal person pay $2k to not have a sump pump under their box... No.

Comment: 1) He's spending the $2k to have the panel replaced anyway.  2) A flush-covered sump *might* be considered OK under 110.26, but I wouldn't count on it; anything protruding upwards from the floor is a no-no, though.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I have had many electricians quote me over 2K MORE to have a panel moved when upgraded.  So basically your note and downvote supports that you can't comprehend my answer.  Because again... you mention that it might be OK which is exactly what I said.  Sorry I didn't say that homeowner should spend as much as possible on electrician costs.

Comment: didn't realize that the panel move cost that much more; I, personally would agree that a flush sump wouldn't count as infringing on the dedicated electrical space, but on the Stack, I prefer to be conservative in how I interpret the NEC.

Comment: (p.s. I didn't downvote your answer)